# How to Use Constants in Swift: AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

This is my working code in Swift. The issue is that I'm using `UInt` as an intermediary type.

```
func handleInterruption(notification: NSNotification) {
    let interruptionType  = notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as! UInt
    if (interruptionType == AVAudioSessionInterruptionType.Began.rawValue) {
        // started
    } else if (interruptionType == AVAudioSessionInterruptionType.Ended.rawValue) {
        // ended
        let interruptionOption  = notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as! UInt
        if interruptionOption == AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions.OptionShouldResume.rawValue {
             // resume!                
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What does "better" mean here?

Comment: `matt` it means that I do not want to go to a `UInt`... I want to go to a `AVAudioSessionInterruptionType`, which is actually a `UInt`

Comment: Well, you can't. What arrives in the `userInfo` dictionary is a UInt (wrapped in an NSNumber). It could hardly be any other way, could it? Objective-C doesn't have enums as objects, does it?

Comment: Objective-C definitely has enums, and Swift provides ways to bridge between some things. I thought there might be a solution here that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Yes, but alas, not in a dictionary. To Objective-C, an enum is just a number - an integer. The only way Objective-C can put a number into a dictionary is wrapped as an NSNumber. I wish this bit of the bridge worked better too, but I don't see how it can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach is similar to Matt's, but due to changes with Swift 3 (mainly `userInfo` being `[AnyHashable : Any]`), we can make our code a little more "Swifty" (no switching on `rawValue` or casting to `AnyObject`, etc.):

```
func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {

    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let interruptionTypeRawValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let interruptionType = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: interruptionTypeRawValue) else {
        return
    }    

    switch interruptionType {
    case .began:
        print("interruption began")
    case .ended:
        print("interruption ended")
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much for your answer to my downvoted question!

Answer (score 4):

```
let interruptionType =
    notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as! UInt
if (interruptionType == AVAudioSessionInterruptionType.Began.rawValue) {
```

The only thing I don't like about that code is the forced `as!`. You're making some big assumptions here, and big assumptions can lead to crashes. Here's a safer way:

```
let why : AnyObject? = note.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey]
if let why = why as? UInt {
    if let why = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: why) {
        if why == .Began {
```

Otherwise, what you're doing is simply how you have to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector: #selector(PlayAudioFile.audioInterrupted), name: AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification, object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
```

---

```
func audioInterrupted(noti: NSNotification) {
    guard noti.name == AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification && noti.userInfo != nil else {
        return
    }

    if let typenumber = noti.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey]?.unsignedIntegerValue {
        switch typenumber {
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionType.Began.rawValue:
            print("interrupted: began")

        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionType.Ended.rawValue:
            print("interrupted: end")

        default:
            break
        }

    }
}
```